# Prototypal inheritance and the value of 'this'

Tags: javascript, this, prototypal-inheritance

I'm building an app with several 'modules'. Each module requires a similar base set of functionality, so I have created a base module that each module will inherit from via prototypal inheritance. Some of the function names on the base module are quite long, and since these functions are used often, I would like to assign shorter names within each module, but this causes issues with the value of 'this' setting it equal to DOMWindow.

Please see the code below:

```
var SAMPLEAPP = SAMPLEAPP || {};

//This is a base module that I want all other modules to inherit from
SAMPLEAPP.Module = function(){

};

SAMPLEAPP.Module.prototype.someLongFunctionName = function(){
    console.log(this);
};


//This is a module that inherits from the base module
SAMPLEAPP.RouterModule= function(){
    var shortName = this.someLongFunctionName;

    //This correctly logs 'SAMPLEAPP.RouterModule', but I would rather not type 
    //out this long function name each time I need to use the function
    this.someLongFunctionName();

    //However, this code logs 'DOMWindow' when I would expect the value of 'this' 
    //to be the same as the direct call to this.someLongFunctionName
    shortName();
};

SAMPLEAPP.RouterModule.prototype = new SAMPLEAPP.Module();


new SAMPLEAPP.RouterModule();
```

My Question: How can I modify the code so that calling shortName() logs SAMPLEAPP.RouterModule? If possible, I would rather change the way the modules are defined than the actual call to shortName (i.e. shortname.call(this), defeats the purpose of creating an alias for someLongFunctionName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can use `call` or `apply` (either will work, the difference is simply how arguments are passed to the function).

Alternatively, you can use the ES5 [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method, which binds a context to a function (in this case the context will be `this`):

```
var shortName = this.someLongFunctionName.bind(this);
```

You can then call `shortName` as you normally would:

```
shortName();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/f3fT8/). And here's the most relevant part of the MDN article:

> The bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the
>   same function body (internal Call attribute in ECMAScript 5 terms) as
>   the function it is being called on (the bound function's target
>   function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(),
>   which cannot be overridden.

Comment: Thanks. This might be the answer, I'll just need to evaluate whether my code & the partial implementation described in the article will work in IE8

Comment: @MarkBrown - The shim described in the MDN article should do the trick. Alternatively, look at [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/), but that may be overkill if this is the only ES5 feature you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the "this" context to the method call, by using the call / apply function. In your case it can be either

```
shortName.apply(this);
```

OR

```
shortName.call(this);
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edits, I would prefer a solution that doesn't require a change to the way I call shortName()

Comment: If your intention is to provide short functions names for long ones, how about using the [module pattern](http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/#module) or [revealing module pattern](http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/#revealing), or even the [revealing prototype pattern](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/08/03/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code-revealing-prototype-pattern.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use a binding function to bind a new context to the function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```
var shortName = this.someLongFunctionName.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the call to `shortName();` to `shortName.call(this);`.

The this is javascript is a bit trick. Is based on context.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edits, I would prefer a solution that doesn't require a change to the way I call shortName()